# Multiple user interfaces using MVVM and Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a desktop WPF project build up nicely in MVVM with Caliburn.Micro and now I'm at the point where I want to add another user interface. That new UI is not for web or phone, that UI is another bunch of Views, completely different from the first UI-set. I should be able to switch between them. One user can select the older UI, another should be able to select the newer. What can I do to be able to switch between different UI's? Sometimes ViewModels are the same, but Views are different, how can I select the required one, depending on the UI-selected?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Screens, Conductors and Composition](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition) of Caliburn.Micro.

Here is a short [Video](https://vimeo.com/16975621).

Furthermore,

You can bind the view Context like so :

```
<clt:TransitioningContentControl cal:View.Context="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 cal:View.Model="{Binding}" 
                                 Style="{StaticResource specialTransition}"/>
```

cal = [`xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"`]

Happy coding :)